# Join and Group By using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Query

```
 var grpby4 = from u in dtEmp.AsEnumerable()
                         join v in dtDept.AsEnumerable() on u.Field<int>("DepartmentID") equals v.Field<int>("DepartmentID")
                         group u by v.Field<string>("DeptName") into g
                         select new { DeptName = g.Key, Records = g };
```

How write the same Query using Lambda Expression?

Comment: Which part do you want to replace with a lambda expression? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm try to execute the same query using lambda expression. I meant both the Join and group by.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this handy webpage](http://lq2m.azurewebsites.net) I get

```
dtEmp.AsEnumerable()
    .Join(dtDept.AsEnumerable(),
        u => u.Field<int>("DepartmentID"),
        v => v.Field<int>("DepartmentID"),
        (u, v) => new { u, v })
    .GroupBy(τ0 => τ0.v.Field<string>("DeptName"), τ0 => τ0.u)
    .Select(g => new { DeptName = g.Key, Records = g })
```